# Using returned functions AND functions as parameters in JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript, function, closures, anonymous-function

I am trying to wrap my head around returned functions and functions as parameters in JavaScript. So far, Ive seen one or the other being used in a function but not both. I have the following code:

```
function adds(num, foo) {
    foo();

    return function(param) {
        document.write("Hello ", param, "<br>");
    };
}

var x = 20;

adds(x, function() {
    x += 2;
})("World");

document.write(x);

//I end up getting:
//Hello World
//22
```

Now my question is, why does the returned function execute first? My understanding is that when adds(); gets called it will make a call to foo(); before the anonymous function is returned. However, this is not the case when we look at the output.

I also understand that this may not be the best way to accomplish things, but for the sake of learning I decided to play around with these concepts.

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've annotated your code with sequentially numbered comments that show the order of execution. You'll notice that the `document.write` inside the callback returned from `adds()` is invoked before the one at the very bottom.

```
function adds(num, foo) {
    foo(); // 3. Call anonymous function

    // 5. Return an anonymous function that receives `param` when invoked
    return function(param) {
        document.write("Hello ", param, "<br>"); // 7. Write "Hello " + "World"
    };
}

var x = 20; // 1. Assignment of 20 to `x`

// 2. Call `add()`, passing `20` and an anonymous function
adds(x, function() {

    x += 2; // 4. Mutate `x` to add `2`. This does not affect `num` above.

}) /* 6. Invoke returned anonymous function --> */ ("World");

document.write(x); // 8. Write the current value of `x` (22) to the document
```

So you are correct that the anonymous function passed to `foo` gets invoked first, there's no side-effect that lets you observe the call. The only side-effect is the mutation of `x`, but that can't be seen until the `document.write()`, which happens after all the other calls.

---

If you put another log in the `foo` anonymous function, you'll be able to see its point of execution more clearly.

```
adds(x, function() {
    document.write("Anon func, mutating `x`" + "<br>");
    x += 2;
})("World");
```

Now the output will be:

```
Anon func, mutating `x`
Hello World
22
```

---

Final note, using `console.log()` is a nicer for observing runtime behavior than `document.write()`.

Comment: makes sense now, thank you! My only other question is what did you mean when you said:                                                                                                // 4. This does not affect `num` above. ?

Comment: @TroyLeu: Glad it helped. What I meant is that while you passed `x` to the `num` parameter of the `adds` function and then mutated the value of `x`, that mutation of `x` does not also mutate `num`. For example if the callback that you return from `adds` were to also write the value of `num`, it would still write `20` even though `x` was changed to `22`.

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking the anonymous function before doing the `document.write` call with `x`. You can defer calling that function to get the result you want.

```
var result = adds(x, function() {
    x += 2;
});

document.write(x);
result("World");
```

Answer (score 0):

in your initial `adds` function

```
function adds(num, foo) {
    // this occurs on the initial function call, inside the scope of the adds function and does not carry over into the returned function.
    foo();

    // returning your function for later use, this will print 'hello' plus your passed in param.
    return function(param) {
        document.write("Hello ", param, "<br>");
    };
}
// set your initial var
var x = 20;
// execute
adds(x/*20*/, function() {\
    // does not relate to the num param inside the adds function for the return
    x/*20*/ += 2;
})("World");
```

Your order of execution is off, I've broken things up a bit for clarity

```
const adds = (number, callback) => {
  return param => {
    // using callback within scope of returned function
    let x = callback(number);
    document.write(`Hello ${x} ${param}`);
  }
};

let x = 20;
let callbackFunc = amount => (amount + 2);
let results = adds(x, callbackFunc);
```

for a slightly more practical real world return function I often use them in places where I need to do some setup to make the callback ready. This allows you to inject your dependencies during setup rather than having to include them all over the place. (helps with decoupling for tests, and organization)

```
module.exports = function(db,logger) {
    return async (req, res) => {
            let result = await db.findOne(/* stuff */);
            if (result.length === 0) {
                logger.error('stuff not found');
                res.sendStatus(404);
            }
            // do some processing, or not.
            res.send(result);
    };
};
```